# Sign a GPG key with multiple own keys in Seahorse

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I have multiple GPG keys.

I want to sign a key with all my keys. How can I do that in Seahorse?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Seahorse. If I want to do it with the command line:

```
gpg --default-key <key to sign with> --edit-key <key to be signed>
gpg> sign
…
```